# ASP.NET Razor RadioButton select multiple radiobuttons, returns data in one field EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm using Entity Framework and from my 6 radio buttons I want to write the value in **code_options**.

How can it be done ?
[image: 6 radiobuttons returns]

After writing I need to read this data.(part 2).

**EDIT** : I was thinking to concatenate 6 strings provided by my 6 radiobuttons and send this to my database. Not sure if it will work.

```
@{
        string po = " "; string sb = " "; string cb = " "; string rl = " "; string pi = " "; string ca = " ";
     }                     

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.panou_ornament)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        Panel ornamental
        @Html.RadioButton(po, "1") DA
        @Html.RadioButton(po, "0") NU            
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">          
        Sticle bombate
        @Html.RadioButton(sb, 1) DA
        @Html.RadioButton(sb, 0) NU
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        Curburi
        @Html.RadioButton(cb, 1) DA
        @Html.RadioButton(cb, 0) NU            
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        Rolete
        @Html.RadioButton(rl, 1) DA
        @Html.RadioButton(rl, 0) NU
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        Profile infoliate
        @Html.RadioButton(pi, 1) DA
        @Html.RadioButton(pi, 0) NU
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        Contractul are si pozitii din aluminiu
        @Html.RadioButton(ca, "1") DA
        @Html.RadioButton(ca, "0") NU
        @Html.Hidden(Model.panou_ornament = po + sb + cb + rl + pi + ca)    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way ASP.NET MVC provides out of the box to do this.  However, you could do this with javascript fairly easily.  Assuming code_options is part of your model, make a hidden input for it:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.code_options)
```

Then hookup click handlers using jQuery and do the necessary binary operations, storing the result in the hidden input you created.  You can find documentation on the bitwise operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Comment: I'm not so good in javascript. Could you give me a small example ?